# How to start in SpyHunter 5 scan offline?

Tags: internet, malware, anti-virus, database, portable

currently I collect good tools to remove malware in sad case of getting infected despite live-protection from AV.

Now I'm interested in SpyHunter 5. Despite being aware of program suspicious past I encountered very good results in finding e.g. bots (like Emotet!) and spyware on actual infected PCs. But I'd like to know a way scanning the computer while it is offline (no internet). But SpyHunter complain about this and ban the scan when not online.

But in case of infection primary rule is you must not give the machine internet access! And besides: I can't seem a reason for SpyHunter needs to be online. There isn't any database loaded at scan start or other things.

**So does anybody know how to scan completely offline with SpyHunter 5?**

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SpyHunter_(software)#Controversies It has very good results because it fakes results. Use MalwareBytes instead

Comment: I can't see how this is related to my problem. To MB: Indeed I use Malwarebytes but some very hard bots have to be detected by additional programs

Comment: @Dragodraki Then reread it in its context. Good luck!

Comment: @Gantendo If you are try to saying SpyHunter is suspicious, yes I heard of this and maybe some of this is still true today, but my experience told me that the program results aren't fake (or not only at least - e.g. my friends computer according to other AV e-mail was infected with Emotet and only SpyHunter was able to locate the file as it changed its path every few minutes ... so not so bad at all I suppose). Please note that the programs behaviour got improved over the last years and everybody deserves a 2nd chance.
--- But this doesn't solve my problem.